# What's the server endpoint for test for GCM or FCM?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

The URL https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send is for production, I want to know the endpoint for test environment as I want test and production to point to different remote systems. 
What is the URL for test?

On this page https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref

there's no mention of any URLs for test environment.

Comment: There is no test environment, you have to use a different project + google_services.json + server api keys for testing

Answer (score 3):

You can send push notification using postman REST api by sending to the url:

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Method: POST
```

don't forget to add inside the header:

```
Authorization:key=yourServerKeyFromFirebaseTestEnvironment
Content-Type:application/json
```

And when you need to send to your test environment, you need to create a firebase test environment and use its server key

Answer (score 0):

Firebase does not provide test environments, you can create a new app in existing project and use API key of that app for testing.